# Finding Data Model(s) in C

Tags: c, architecture, datamodel

Is it safe to assume:

```
#if defined(_M_X64) || defined(_M_AMD64) || (defined(_M_IA64) && !defined(__itanuim__))
/* LLP64 Data Model */
#elif defined(__amd64__) || defined(__ia64__) || defined(__ia64) || defined(__itanuim__)
/* LP64 Data Model */
#else
/* 32-bits Data Model(s) */
#endif
```

for Unix, BSD, Windows, Linux and HP? or I'm totally wrong :-) or missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on why you would want to assume that, I guess. If you're on a `__sparc__`, then assuming such would get you into trouble, but if you don't intend for your code to work in such a case, you might be able to get away with that assumption...

Comment: @twalberg `__sparc__` or `__sparc` uses ILP64 in 64bit and ILP32 in 32bit system, am I right?

Comment: Right. But really, my point was that the highlighted list in the OP isn't particularly exhaustive. And Linux and Unix both apply to SPARC systems. There might even be a BSD port there, but I'm not sure of that.

Comment: @twalberg thanks for your reply. Here what I have to do. I need to create types like int32_t, ... (I've been reading on it here and other websites). I'm not allowed to use `stdint.h` or equivalent (Work stuff). Now I'm trying to find WORDSIZE for those arch. So my plan was to find the data model and if it's ILP64, LLP64 or LP64, WORDSIZE is 64, otherwise 32. Can I assume that?

Comment: Are you looking for the natural word size on the underlying hardware - i.e. register size? I'm not sure relying on a particular compiler's implementation can really get you that. You could have a 64-bit platform that has a 32-bit tool chain on it that might indicate ILP32. It's even feasible (although I don't know that it's been done) to have an underlying 16-bit platform that has a compiler environment providing LP64 (although very inefficiently, and I wouldn't want to work with it...).

Comment: @twalberg Any suggestion on how to approach my problem? No not register size (I don't even know if that's possible). if WORDSIZE is 64 that means I can use `long int` and if it's 32 I would use `long long int` for 64 bit integer (If it has LONG LONG) otherwise I'll define `struct`.

Comment: Well, the approach you're taking, as long as you are aware of the assumptions you are making, is probably nearly the best you can do - but my point is it really determines the word size / data model for the toolchain you're using, not necessarily the underlying hardware. The 32-bit tools on 64-bit platform case is still quite common. Computing the hardware characteristics directly is architecture- and tool-dependent. Sometimes it's easy (e.g. Linux /proc and /sys), sometimes not so much.

Comment: Another route would be `sizeof(int)/sizeof(char)`, which would indicate 4 for 32-bit, 8 for 64-bit; substitute `long` and/or `long long` as appropriate. That should be portable, without relying on your compiler to provide a certain set of predefined macros (which most do, but they're not fully standardized or complete).

Comment: @twalberg, `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`.

Comment: @JensGustedt Right, so `sizeof(blah)/sizeof(char)` is a slightly more redundant form of `sizeof(blah)`. Old habits die hard, I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't have `UINT_MAX` and Co available through include files you can at least determine `UINTMAX_MAX`:

```
typedef unsigned long long uintmax_t;
typedef signed long long intmax_t;

// start testing with the smaller values
#if -1U == 4294967295U
# define UINTMAX_MAX 4294967295
#elif -1U == 18446744073709551615U
...
#endif
```

The preprocessor computes with the same width as `uintmax_t`. So you'd know at least that part of the architecture.

For other things I would write a test code that creates a small include file:

```
printf("#define CHAR_IS_SIGNED %d\n", ((char)-1 < 0));
printf("#define UCHAR_MAX %hhu\n", (unsigned char)-1);
printf("#define USHRT_MAX %hu\n", (unsigned short)-1);
printf("#define UINT_MAX %u\n", (unsigned)-1);
printf("#define ULONG_MAX %lu\n", (unsigned long)-1);
printf("#define ULLONG_MAX %llu\n", (unsigned long long)-1);
```

Under reasonable assumptions (two's complement, no padding bits) you may then deduce the values for the signed types and also you'd be able to do the correct `typedef` for the `uintXX_t` types.

Comment: How can I be sure that `long long` exists?

Comment: Thanks. Do you by any chance why `glibc` uses predefined macros instead of finding max of `int`?

Comment: @markfw, you mean these special gcc macros that specify the sizes? I guess these values are all fixed when compiling the compiler for a specific platform. So gcc knows all these values and may as well export them to the library.